Golden ratio pattern in Sierpinski matrix eigenvalues
Stumbled onto the following observation.
Defining a Sierpinski matrix recursively
import numpy as np
def sierpinski(n):
    """ Generate a Sierpinski triangle matrix"""
    size = 2**n + 1
    triangle = np.zeros((size, size), dtype=int)

    def fill_triangle(x, y, side_length):
        if side_length == 1:
            triangle[x, y] = 1
        else:
            new_length = side_length // 2
            fill_triangle(x, y, new_length)  # Top vertex triangle
            fill_triangle(x + new_length, y, new_length)  # Left vertex triangle
            fill_triangle(x, y + new_length, new_length)  # Right vertex triangle

    fill_triangle(0, 0, size-1)
    return triangle

k=0
# Generate Sierpinski triangle matrix k
sierpinski_triangle = sierpinski(k)
sierpinski_triangle

I couldn't help but notice that eigenvalues of these matrices seem to involve the Golden ratio $\phi^{\pm}=\frac{1\pm \sqrt5}{2}$. Since there is a pattern in the definition of these matrices, is there a discernible pattern in the eigenvalues in terms of $\phi$?
The first few...
$0$
$0,1$
$0,\phi^{+},\phi^{-}$
$0,1,-1,\phi^{+}+1,\phi^{-}+1$
...

Does the next one? As the degrees of these polynomials grow, it might be that the appearance of the quadratic irrational $\phi$ was a transient phenomenon.

@GregMartin I thought that as well, but I think the connection is there. I checked $n$ up to 10 and the largest eigenvalue is $\phi^n$ to several digits. (+1, nice question.)

I can't tell what generates the eigenvector associated to $\phi^n$ (what seems to be the largest eigenvalue)

https://i.imgur.com/WyPqmSj.png for n=8, here are the sorted eigenvector entries. I cannot seem to find some kind of closed form, perhaps it's related to the fourier breakdown of the s-triangle?

Please, have a look at my answer (complementing the remarkable answer of Daniel Areolla).

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. If I understand your construction correctly, Sierpinski(n) is the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} A^{\otimes n} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ where $A^{\otimes n} = A \otimes \cdots \otimes A$ is the Kronecker product of $A$ with itself $n$ times. Since the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\phi^{\pm}$, the eigenvalues of $A^{\otimes n}$ are of the form $\lambda_i = (\phi^+)^i(\phi^-)^{n-i}$ for $i=0,\ldots,n$. In fact, $\lambda_i$ has multiplicity $\binom{n}{i}$.

[+1] very nice answer. In this article, the OP will find connected information.

Surprisingly short proof and nice connection between these two. I guess it was unexpected to find something rectangular about a triangle but I see now that it comes from the 2x2 linear transformation. Both are related to pascal's triangle.

+1, perfect short answer.

What about the eigenvector associated with $\lambda_i$? Does that play nicely with the product structure? Looking into it

@Snared Yes, the eigenvectors for $A^{\otimes n}$ are just Kronecker products of $n$ eigenvectors for $A$. For example, if $Av^+ = \phi^+ v^+$ and $Av^- = \phi^- v^-$, then $(A \otimes A)(v^+ \otimes v^-) = Av^+ \otimes Av^- = \phi^+\phi^-(v^+ \otimes v^-)$.

Connected : this answer to a question with several other interesting answers.

Please have a look at my answer complementing yours.

@DanielArreola How come when I write the eigenvectors of $A$ as a matrix $E$ and take $E^{\otimes 2}$, it is not equal to the eigenvector matrix of $A^{\otimes2}$ then? The first column was the same (up to sign), but it begins to differ on the second column

@Snared What do you mean by "the eigenenvector matrix"? Such a matrix is not unique. There are many bases consisting of eigenvectors.

Illustration of the method of Daniel Arreola :
As you use Python, here is how iteration of Kronecker product (aka tensor product) of matrices can be programmed, with a display using "spy" function :
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import numpy as np
 n=7
 N=matrix([[1,1],[1,0]])
 M=matrix([1])
 for k in range(n) :
    M=N.tensor_product(M)   
 plt.spy(M,origin='upper')
 plt.show()


Fig. 1 : Sierpinki matrix. Black squares are for "ones" entries.
If you use 'lower' instead of 'upper', you get (Fig. 2) the more classical Sierpinski triangle (which can be described as "Pascal triangle mod $2$)

Fig. 2.
Remark : If you want to check for example the eigenvalues of $M$ with their order of multiplicity, just add (at the right place...)
 from numpy import linalg as LA 
 from collections import Counter
 eVa,eVe=LA.eig(M)
 eVa = list(map(lambda x: round(x,5),real(eVa)))
 eVac = Counter(eVa)

giving, in the case at hand :
$$\begin{array}{rrr}-1.61803&:&35\\ +0.61803&:&35\\+4.23607 &:& 21\\ -0.23607&:&21\\ -11.09017&:&7\\+0.09017&:&7\\ +29.03444&:& 1\\ -0.03444&:& 1\end{array}$$
where the orders of multiplicity $1,7,21,35,35,21,7,1$ are indeed the binomial coefficients of line number $7$ in Pascal's triangle.
